# CSS: switch from 3 to 2 then to 1 column and aligning elements at the bottom of each other

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float

This is my first question,

I am trying to make a template that except the `header`, `nav`, and footer to be:

1) Three columns above `950px`(already done)

2) Two columns when @media screen and (`max-width: 950px`) and (`min-width: 651px`)

3) One column for @media screen and (`max-width: 650px`)
(already done by switching the order of items using flexbox)

The problem I am having is in number 2) due to the widget "CSS Links" is not getting under "HTML Links" but a lot of useless space as you can see between 651px and 950px of this template:

here you can see the element at the bottom left:

[image]

https://atheerhuwaish.github.io/2

How to make them under each other either by flexbox or using float?

HTML

```css
body{margin:2%;
 background-color:rgba(49,119,195,0.7);
  }
  
#container{margin:2%;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 background-color:rgba(79,59,105,0.7);
  color:white;
 }
  
    
footer, header{order:1;
width:100%;
height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(179,59,105,0.7);
 }

nav{order:2;
height:20px
 text-align: center;
  background-color:rgba(149,59,195,0.7);
 width:100%
}


h1,h2,h3,h4,nav,aside{text-align: center;}

 
aside.aside1{order:3;}
aside.aside2{order: 5;}


main{order:4;
 width: 58%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:rgba(244,244,255,0.9);
}
  

footer{order:6;
 background-color:rgba(99,119,145,.8);
 margin: 2% auto;
 width:100%;
 }

ul li {list-style: none;}


aside{
 background-color:rgba(244,244,255,0.9);
 padding:3% 0;
 margin: 0;
 height:100%;
 width: 20%
  }

  
aside li {text-align:center;
  padding: 4% 0;
  margin: 4% 0
   }

aside li b{background-color: #c9c9dd;
  padding: 4% 1%;
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%
    }
    
    

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) and (min-width: 651px)
{

 #container{margin: 0;}
 .aside1{flex-basis:25%;}
 .aside2{flex-basis:25%;}
 main{flex-basis:73%;}

}


  
  
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) 
{

aside.aside1{width:46%; margin:0; padding: 1%}
aside.aside2{order:4; width:46%; margin: 0 0 1% 4%; padding: 1%} 



main{order: 5;
 width:100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">

 <header>
        header
  </header>
  
  <nav>
    nav
 </nav>

 
 <aside class="aside1">
  <ul><li>
           <b><a href="#">HTML Links</a></b>  
   </li>
  </ul>
 </aside>

 
 <aside class="aside2">
    <ul><li>
     <b><a href="#">CSS Links</a></b>
   </li></ul>
 </aside>
  
  <main>
      <p style="height:500px"></p>
  </main>
  
  <footer>
        footer
  </footer>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So im not sure if using flexbox and order commands is something you require but here is an alternative that does go 3 column, 2 column, then 1 at the sizes you mentioned.

I think the issue is order doesnt work well with altering the layout but using floats and widths you can do it: [

```
aside.aside1 {
order: 3;
}
```

]
https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/BONBzg?editors=1100

It is somewhat basic and you can fine tune the css to get the widths and alignment how you want.

EDIT:

add this to media screen 650 max:

```
.clearfix {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.one-fourth,
  .two-fourths {
    float:none;
    width:100%;

  }
  .one-fourth.first {
    order:1;
  }
  .one-fourth.last {
    order:2;
  }
  .two-fourths {
    order:3;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Moose,
That solved the problem other than it caused now the CSS Links not to be directly below HTML Links in the smallest view under 650px.

Comment: oh my mistake, see answer for updated answer and codepen!